# jQuery UI sortable - need to remove absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I have successfully got the jQuery UI working on my page to move items from one UL to another UL.

The problem I'm having is that UL A's items have absolute positioning on each li, and when the items are dragged to UL B, the UI seems to add the previous positioning rules as an inline style, thus completely messing up the appearance of my interface.

UL A is a circle, with the various LI's going round it by using absolute positioning.

UL B is a horizontal nav, with display inline and no positioning.

**How do I get the UI to remove the previous absolutely positioned styles?**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("ul#navCircle, #footer ul").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectList'
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
update: function(){
  //remove style from the element here
},
```

option in the sortable which fires on each update to the target.